# Creating Dictionary<string, Dictionary<T, T[]>[]>

Tags: c#, .net

In C#, what is the syntax for instantiating and initializing a dictionary containing as values an array of dictionaries, those dictionaries themselves containing arrays as values?

For example, (I believe),

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string[]>[]>?
```

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
private static readonly Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, DirectoryInfo[]>[]> OrderTypeToFulfillmentDict = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, DirectoryInfo[]>>()
    {
        {"Type1", new [] 
                { 
                    ProductsInfo.Type1FulfillmentNoSurfacesLocations, 
                    ProductsInfo.Type2FulfillmentSurfacesLocations 
                } 
        }
    }
```

where Type1Fulfillment..., and Type2Fulfillment... are already constructed as

```
Dictionary<string, DirectoryInfo[]>.
```

This throws the following compiler error:

```
"Cannot convert from System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, System.IO.DirectoryInfo[]>[] to System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, System.IO.DirectoryInfo[]>"
```

Edit: The problem was, as Lanorkin pointed out, that I was missing the final `[]` in the new `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, DirectoryInfo[]>>()`. Still, it goes without saying that this probably isn't something anyone should be trying to do in the first place.

Comment: Looks correct. Have you tried it?

Comment: It's *declaration* and not *initializing* he asks for

Comment: the hard part is not creation.it's initialization

Comment: @Andrei, I've edited the question to show the specific code that isn't working.

Comment: @furkle what is the exact type of `ProductsInfo.Type1FulfillmentNoSurfacesLocations` ?

Comment: If I saw something like `MyDictionary["Key2OtherDictionary"][someIndex]["KeyToSomeCollectionOfStrings"][anotherIndex]`, I think I would have a mini heart attack.

Comment: `...DirectoryInfo[]>[]> = new ...DirectoryInfo[]>>()` - feel the difference, you need extra `[]` at the end: `var x = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, DirectoryInfo[]>[]> { { "key1", new[] { x1, x2 } } }` works perfect

Comment: @Selman22, looks like my <T> got misinterpreted as formatting tags, it's fixed now.

Comment: @furkle It seems the type of the `ProductsInfo.Type1FulfillmentNoSurfacesLocations` is `Dictionary<string, System.IO.DirectoryInfo[]>[]` instaed of single `Dictionary<string, System.IO.DirectoryInfo[]>`. Can you show us the initialization of your productinfos ?

Comment: @Jordy, the fact that I'm struggling to figure out exactly what part of the initialization is incorrect means Sean's right and I really just need to restructure some parts of this in order to add surface-specific functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you've got looks correct, but what you're doing has a real [code smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) about it that's going to lead to some serious [technical debt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_debt).

For starters, rather than having an inner `Dictionary<string, string[]>` model this in a class with methods appropriate to what you're trying to model. Otherwise anyone accessing this type isn't going to have a clue about what it's really modeling.

Comment: That's the feeling I'm starting to get, but I'm struggling to figure out exactly how best to model it. There needs to be a specific UNC path returned based on - in order - the software from which the order originated, whether or not the product in question can be printed on multiple surfaces, and the ID of the product itself. Guess it's back to the drawing board on this one.

Comment: Accepted for the well-needed rap on the knuckles.

Comment: @furkle for *private* classes it still can be possible to use such approach (just don't show it to any one and don't use it in public methods), but you can simplify that by using `using MyMegaType = Dictionary<string, DirectoryInfo[]>;` synonyms, and then use it inside dictionary like `new Dictionary<string, MyMegaType[]>`

Comment: @Lanorkin you actually had the correct answer in your comment above - I didn't notice it until a few seconds after I'd finally seen the same thing in my code. I think I'm just going to separate out the workflows into static classes rather than trying (stupidly, against deadlines) to encapsulate the entirety of the fulfillment workflow in a single dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
var dic = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, int[]>[]>
        {
            {
                "key1", 
                new[]
                {
                    new Dictionary<int, int[]>
                    {
                        {1, new[] {1, 2, 3, 4}}
                    }
                }}
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string[]>[]> complexDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string[]>[]>();
```

or using the `var` keyword:

```
var complexDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string[]>[]>();
```

Answer (score 1):

The following is perfectly valid

```
     // array of dictionary
     Dictionary<int, string[]>[] matrix = new Dictionary<int, string[]>[4];

//Dictionary of string and dictionary array
 Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string[]>[]> dicOfArrays= new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string[]>[]>();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 private static readonly Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, DirectoryInfo[]>> 

OrderTypeToFulfillmentDict = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, DirectoryInfo[]>>()
     {
         {"Type1", new [] 
            { 
                ProductsInfo.Type1FulfillmentNoSurfacesLocations, 
                ProductsInfo.Type2FulfillmentSurfacesLocations 
            } 
    }
}
```

You have the wrong type in your variable definition.  Remove the final "[]" as you don't want an array of dictionaries.